# How do I avoid redirecting 404's to the login form in a Zend Framework 1 controller plugin?

Tags: zend-framework

I made a controller plugin to handle authentication.  If a user tries to access a page without being logged in, it saves the route of the page he was trying to access, forwards to the login page, and then when the user logs in, it redirects him to where he was trying to go.

But if the user tries to access a nonexistent page while logged out, then it still forwards to the sign-in form, but when the user signs in, it brings up an error.

How do I bring up a 404 error before the user signs in?  I think I need to detect whether the route is valid within dispatchLoopStartup().  How do I do that?  Or is there some other way of doing this?

```
class Chronos_Controller_Plugin_Auth extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $request->setParam('userName', $auth->getIdentity());
        } else {
            $request->setParam('origModule', $request->getModuleName())
                    ->setParam('origController', $request->getControllerName())
                    ->setParam('origAction', $request->getActionName())
                    ->setModuleName('default')
                    ->setControllerName('sign')
                    ->setActionName('in');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what would be useful to show.  I've added my controller plugin code.

Comment: if nothing else it show how you're thinking about the problem.

Comment: Maybe I should just call dispatch myself in a try block?

Comment: you could probably find a way in your login redirect to intercept the Response code and force a redirect if not 200. `Zend_Controller_Front::getResponse();` may be helpful. What you really want though is get the return from `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module::match()` (returns false on mismatch) but I haven't figured out how drill down to it from the plugin yet

Comment: i would just check if the requested controller is the errorController. If yes dont jump into authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $request->setParam('userName', $auth->getIdentity());
    } else if ($dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)) {
        $request->setParam('origModule', $request->getModuleName())
                ->setParam('origController', $request->getControllerName())
                ->setParam('origAction', $request->getActionName())
                ->setModuleName('default')
                ->setControllerName('sign')
                ->setActionName('in');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice and simple to boot :)